# Permit Duplicate Root Login No

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, lubuntu

How i can disable duplicate root/others user access from different device concurrently in Linux Terminal Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate root/others user access from different device concurrently"?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by defining the `maxlogins` in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
#       -  maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
```

Example:

```
@student     -      maxlogins      1
root         -      maxlogins      1
```